# Why is my VBA SUMIFS function returning zeros?

Tags: excel, vba

First, allow me to thank you for any help you are able to lend me. I appreciate it! (:

My issue is this: I have two workbooks, one with raw data, and one in which the raw data is consolidated into relevant statistics. I am trying to SUMIFS the data in X:X in my raw data workbook (6620) by two criteria in the results book and then update the value in the corresponding cell in the results book.

The problem is that the macro returns all zeros. I have double checked the data types, names, ranges, etc, but no luck. Leaving me to think there is something wonky in my code.

I include two photos at the end of this post of example raw data and results tables so you can see what I am working from.

```
Sub ImportFTEs()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

        Dim ws As Integer

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\6620\FY19*.xlsb"
            For ws = 1 To Worksheets.Count
                Sheets(ws).Name = "Sheet1"
            Next ws

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim l As Integer
        Dim totalFTE As Long
        Dim lastRow As Integer
            lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim wb_a As Worksheet
            Set wb_a = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\FY19*.xlsb").Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim wb_b As Worksheet
            Set wb_b = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B")
        Dim sumRange As Range
            Set sumRange = wb_a.Range("X:X")
        Dim cRange1 As Range
            Set cRange1 = wb_a.Range("D:D")
        Dim criteria1 As Range
        Dim cRange2 As Range
            Set cRange2 = wb_a.Range("S:S")
        Dim criteria2 As Range
            For k = 8 To 18
                For l = 7 To 18
                    For i = 7 To 18
                    Set criteria1 = wb_b.Cells(7, i)
                        For j = 8 To 18
                        Set criteria2 = wb_b.Cells(j, 6)
                            wb_b.Cells(k, l).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(sumRange, cRange1, criteria1, cRange2, criteria2)
                        Next j
                    Next i
                Next l
            Next k
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[image: Raw Data Table]

[image: Results Table]

Comment: Why do you rename every (maybe only one existing) sheet as „Sheet1“?

Comment: `Dim lastRow As Integer` ... in modern Excel, the number of rows can exceed what an integer can hold. There is no reason to use `Integer` in Excel VBA. Use `Long` instead.

Comment: Yah, it is only ever one sheet. But every month a new sheet is dropped into the folder with a sheet name that is either random or I simply cannot understand the logic behind. So, I just want to rename it and move on.

Comment: Interesting mix of criteria from different workbooks within one SUMIF. Can not test that actually. If that‘s not the reason for non-working, I learn‘t something new and interesting.

Comment: @Asger And that is not even the complete list of criteria. I heavily edited it down. But Tate Garringer identified the issue as my excess use of loops below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need so many nested loops. Your original code is looping through every possible criteria for each `k` and `l`. Assuming `wb_b.Cells(k, l)` is supposed to be a reference to the cell intersected by your month column and employee name row, you could use your `i` and `j` values.

```
For i = 7 To 18
    Set Criteria1 = wb_b.Cells(7, i)
    For j = 8 To 18
        Set Criteria2 = wb_b.Cells(j, 6)
        wb_b.Cells(j, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(sumRange, cRange1, Criteria1, cRange2, Criteria2)
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: It worked! You are brilliant! I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much, Tate!

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Comment: Congrats for hitting 1K! Keep 'em coming!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks! I've been lurking SO since the beginning of time, the New Year seemed like an appropriate time to start giving back.